# Adding a location field with STPointFromText into azure mobile service

Tags: javascript, azure, server-side

I have azure mobile services database. I am trying to put data into it adding location field on server side. Source code I am using is below. The problem is that server responds with "internal server error" and my client throws 'MobileServiceInvalidOperationException' but tha data is added. If I add request.execute() to success function instead of request.respond() it works fine but adds additional row in table which I don't want. How can I put a data into database without getting "internal server error" ?

```
 function insert(item, user, request) { 
        var queryString = "INSERT INTO mytable (name, city, country, latitude, longitude, location) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, geography::STPointFromText('POINT(' + ? + ' ' + ? + ')', 4326))";         
        mssql.query(queryString, [item.name, item.city, item.country, item.latitude, item.longitude, item.longitude.toString(), item.latitude.toString()], { 
                    success: function() {                     
                        request.respond(); 
                    }

              }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move your call to STPointFromText() outside your queryString.  For example,

```
 function insert(item, user, request) { 
        var location = geography::STPointFromText ....
        var queryString = "INSERT INTO mytable (name, city, country, latitude, longitude, location) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";         
        mssql.query(queryString, [item.name, item.city, item.country, item.latitude, item.longitude, location], { 
                    success: function() {                     
                        request.respond(); 
                    }

              }); 
    }
```

If that doesn't help, then look in the logs for some additional information about the error.

Comment: Doesn't help, just says " geography' is not defined.
any"

Comment: Is geography::STPointFromText shared code???  How is Mobile Services supposed to resolve this?  You could wrap that functionality into a service, and then just call the service to hydrate your location variable.

Comment: My code is based on code from the article - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Geolocation-sample-end-to-5d9ee245. I have just added some properties.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you use `InsertAsync` on client side it's expecting response with item you insert and with new Id in database. So you must update line with proper response to this:

```
request.respond(statusCodes.CREATED, item);
```

and on client side after InsertAsync you have Id in your item:

```
await actionTable.InsertAsync(action);
var id = item.Id;
```